# Енумератор слишком рано завершает работу

Tags: c#, дерево

Суть задачи: обойти дерево (preorder), но у меня не получается вернуть нормальную `IEnumerable<VisualElement>`, возвращается только первый элемент и на этом цикл заканчивается. Алгоритм правильный, поскольку если метод сделать void и вместо `yield return root` сделать `Console.WriteLine(root)`, то всё выводится в правильном порядке.

```
public static IEnumerable<VisualElement> GetChildren(VisualElement root)
{
    yield return root;
    if (root?.Children != null)
        foreach (var child in root.Children)
        {
            GetChildren(child);
        }
}
```

Конечно, можно добавить поле `List<VisualElement>`, и вместо `yield return` сделать добавление в коллекцию, но мне кажется этот способ плохим, поскольку при повторном запуске метода `List` будет непустым.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рекурсия же

```
public static IEnumerable<VisualElement> GetChildren(VisualElement root)
{
    yield return root;
    if (root?.Children != null)
        foreach (var child in root.Children)
        {
            GetChildren(child); // <-- отсюда значения не забираете
        }
}
```

То есть надо энумератором так же вытаскивать значения из дочерних вызовов

```
public static IEnumerable<VisualElement> GetChildren(VisualElement root)
{
    yield return root;
    if (root?.Children != null)
        foreach (var child in root.Children)
        {
            foreach (var node in GetChildren(child))
                yield return node;
        }
}
```

Стоит только обратить внимание, что данная рекурсия хвостовая и можно оптимизировать до цикла, полностью избавившись от рекурсии.

Comment: Я был бы рад, если бы вы показали оптимизацию, я пытался через неё изначально сделать, но не получилось

Comment: @Kalmankantaja Задайте отдельный вопрос, напишу там код, или не я напишу. Это проще простого. Классический обход графа, школьная задачка.

Comment: Я почему-то думал, что в C# сделали наконец-то что-то типа `yield return from`, чтобы циклы перебора не писать, но видимо так и нет. А жаль )

Comment: @CrazyElf ага, еще и во время debug не зайти в итератор, он будет просто скипаться. Надо ToList() ставить чтобы зашел в метод. Даже issue на гитхабе по этому поводу есть

Comment: @CrazyElf и не сделают, это решается без yield через Concat/Append или оберткой на базе SelectMany