# Реализовать в классе итератор, обходящий узлы дерева в "глубину" в обратном направлении

Tags: c#

Написал только через рекурсию обход в глубину, но как это реализовать через итератор?

```
public class Tree
{
    public class TreeNode
    {
        public int Value;
        public TreeNode Left; 
        public TreeNode Right;
    }
    
    
    public void Add(ref TreeNode node, int value)
    {
        node.Value = value;
    }
        
    public void CRL(TreeNode node, ref string s)
    {
        if (node != null)
        {
            CRL(node.Left, ref s);
            CRL(node.Right, ref s); 
            s += node.Value.ToString() + " "; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1445862/373567

Comment: Слишком сложный код... Можно с моим что-нибудь придумать?

Comment: Вы просили итератор с обходом, я дал итератор с обходом. В вопросе кстати тоже рабочий код. Для итератора придется возиться с вложенными итераторами, а это потребует дополнительных циклов, возмите код из вопроса, просто он там с рекурсией, а в ответе без рекурсии.